# Proof that a function $\phi$ is a contraction by assuming related function $f$ is locally Lipschitz?

Tags: metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I have used the assumption that a function, $f$ is everywhere Lipschitz to prove that another function, $\phi$, is a contraction. The function in question is
\begin{equation}
\phi(y,t) = y_0 +  \int_{0}^{t} f(y(s)) ds 
\end{equation}

And the metric space in question, $X$, is the space of all bounded, continuous functions between $0$ and $T$.

The metric in use is
\begin{equation}
d(f,g) = \max_{t\in[0,T]}|f(t)-g(t)|
\end{equation}

So I start with
\begin{equation}
|\phi(y_1)-\phi(y_2)| = |\;y_0 +  \int_{0}^{t} f(y_1(s))ds \;-(y_0 +  \int_{0}^{t} f(y_2(s))ds) \;|
\end{equation}

Simplifying to
\begin{equation}
|\phi(y_1)-\phi(y_2)| = \;|  \int_{0}^{t} f(y_1(s))-f(y_2(s))ds \;| 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=  \int_{0}^{t} |\;f(y_1(s))-f(y_2(s))\;|\;ds \; 
\end{equation}

Which by the Lipschitz condition is
\begin{equation}
\le K \cdot \;\int_{0}^{t} |\;y_1(s)-y_2(s)\;|\;ds \; 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\le K \cdot \;\int_{0}^{t} \max_{t\in[0,T]}|\;y_1-y_2\;|\;ds \; 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= K \cdot \max_{t\in[0,T]}|\;y_1-y_2\;| \cdot \;\int_{0}^{t} 1\;ds \; 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= K \cdot t\cdot \max_{t\in[0,T]}|\;y_1-y_2\;|  
\end{equation}

So if we have $c = Kt$, this meets the criteria that $\phi$ is a contraction.

I have now been asked to try and show that $\phi$ is a contraction if we assume that the function $f$ is LOCALLY Lipschitz. I believe this means that the Lipschitz condition only holds for restricted range of values of $y$.

I apologise if my work seems a bit disjointed or I have not fully explained a certain step in my proof. All I am asking is if anyone would understand how the change from everywhere Lipschitz to locally Lipschitz affects the proof. Does the proof still have a similar structure in general? What aspect of the proof changes? All help appreciated!

Comment: Which function is locally Lipschitz, $\varphi, y$ or $f$?

Comment: $f$ in this case, sorry for not making that clear